# Python script not working if i run it using full path

Tags: cron, python-3.4

I have my python script in sub directory test of directory PycharmProjects. It is working fine if i run it by following steps:

1. cd PycharmProjects/test
2. python3 xmll.py

It is not working if i try to run it directly by doing:

/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/myname/PycharmProjects/test/xmll.py

I need full path for cron job.

Comment: Are any error messages displayed?

Comment: yes.... errors are about my code but it is working fine if i run it using first steps i mentioned

Comment: File "parser.pxi", line 620, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91722)
OSError: Error reading file 'data1.xml': failed to load external entity "data1.xml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a job, cron invokes the job from the current users home directory. In this case cron runs your script as if it were in the directory `/home/myname`, instead of `/home/myname/PycharmProjects/test`.

This means that Python is looking for `data1.xml` in `/home/myname`.

Update your code and change `data1.xml` to be an absolute path.

```
/home/myname/PycharmProjects/test/data1.xml
```

Or relative to your home directory

```
PycharmProjects/test/data1.xml
```

Comment: Thanks Noah it was helpful. :)